# Why does Sphinx+MyST put spaces inside HTML tags in the generated output?

Tags: python-sphinx, myst

I'm new to [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), so perhaps this has an obvious explanation, but it is not obvious to me.  Whenever I use any construct in my Markdown source, such as bold facing or italics or even an html element such as `<span>`, the result in the formatted HTML output contains spaces inside the HTML tags. For example, an input such as

```
* **Barcode**: the barcode identifying the item
* **Title**: the title of the item.
* **Author**: the author of the item.
```

produces this:

[image]

Note the space before the `:`. Inspecting the HTML reveals that the bold-faced element contains unexpected space characters:

[image]

Note the spaces inside the `<strong>...</strong>`. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? More importantly, how do I make it stop?

I'm using Sphinx 3.4.3 with `myst-parser` 0.13.3. My `conf.py` defines `extensions` as 'myst_parser',    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',    'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel',  and  'sphinx.ext.napoleon'.

Comment: I picked this as an example, but it happens in other cases too. However, thanks for narrowing the possible cause. That's helpful.

Comment: I have to slightly rewrite my previous comment for clarity in case future readers come across it, so I'll post another version and delete the previous one.

Comment: In ReST the example is a [bullet list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists) (it is not a "field list" because there's no second colon surrounding the name). I checked and in ReST+Sphinx neither the lists nor the [emphasis](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#emphasis) add extra spaces inside the HTML tags. The example may be in [MyST markdown](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/faq.html), I searched the MyST documentation but found no immediate explanation for the spaces being added.

Comment: FWIW, I tried your sample reST with only Sphinx in the stack, and no spaces were added in the HTML output. That isolates the cause to either Myst or Napolean. My guess is Myst, but I don't see any [relevant issues](https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser/issues?q=space).

Comment: StevePiercy to complement, napoleon doesn't cause the spaces for me. I think this is MyST specific, I can't recall any instance or configuration option in Sphinx or its  well established extensions causing this issue. My guess (from the last link in my previous comment) is the MyST parser wraps any field in spaces before feeding it to Sphinx-docutils engine. (@mhucka your best bet at this point is probably posting this bug/feature issue on GitHub).

Comment: Having considered the MyST specifics, I think the question isn't providing full information. It's not clear if the example code is in a `.rst` file; if it's being processed/included as `.rst` in a larger context of a `Markdown` file or another variant that MyST allows to process. Because MyST apparently has different techniques to include `ReST`/Markdown in different structure-language scopes and choosing different parsers/flattening for each file (these type of issues don't usually have overlap in the most common uses-cases of Sphinx).

Comment: @bad_coder My apologies for the lack of details. I'll try to produce a minimal example and update the question with more info, hopefully in the next 24 hrs.

Comment: @mhucka no need to apologize it's no problem. This question captured my interest and I tried to contribute what would be my preliminary analyses in the hope it might be helpful. This kind of problem is frequently an evolving issue, many of the best Sphinx questions don't get fully formulated in the first attempt. Take your time, my best advice is still posting on github where StevePiercy indicated, there you'll find the devs that are most focused on MyST in particular (and to that end, this initial exchange should also prove useful.)

Comment: I finally created a fresh test, then systematically added `conf.py` options from the configuration that led to this question, and have now found the culprit – and it is not MyST. I was using the Sphinx Material theme, and the option `html_prettify` for that theme. Using that option causes the HTML to be reformatted in some unexpected ways, and what I described here was a consequence of that. This was a case of me not reading the documentation carefully. Given this whole posting here is now quite off the mark, I'm tempted to delete it altogether. Do you agree?